# .NET Shadow Copy Assembly Cache not being created

Tags: .net, windows, silverlight, dll, .net-assembly

Firstly, I apologise that I am NOT a developer...

We're using a third-party web-based application that uses .NET and Silverlight.  I don't know if it's .NET v2 or .NET v3.5 that it uses but we're using Windows 7.  We have a group of PCs where a control does not appear on a page in the app.  From what I can tell, these are connected with DLLs which are stored in "C:\windows\Downloaded Program Files" and should be being copied to the per-profile shadow copy assembly cache.  On working machines, this cache is created ("c:\users\%username%\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3") correctly and populated with the DLLs.  On the affected ones (done from a common image), the assembly folder is not created in the profile at all.  I tried manually adding a "DownloadCacheLocation" string into the Fusion key of HKCU to encourage it but to no avail.
An affected PC has been stripped back to almost nothing and fully patched but is still misbehaving.  I am not aware of anything odd having been done to the affected PCs (they were cloned from a vey basic sysprepped image).  The website runs in the Trusted Zone and I've set that zone to minimum security.
Do you have any idea what might cause the cache to not be created?

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: Having spent two days on this, I've just found a big clue.  The OK PCs had .NET v4.0 on whereas the affected ones had .NET v4.5.  **If I remove .NET v4.5, the app works**.  If I add v4.5 back, it breaks again.  If I remove v4.5 and add v4 it's OK but breaks if I then upgrade to 4.5.  Can this be worked around without removing v4.5?

Comment: It also fails with .NET v4.5.1 Release Candidate.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887.aspx#web

"Managed browser hosting controls from the .NET Framework 1.1 and 2.0" - "Hosting these controls is blocked in Internet Explorer."

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar dl3 cache error, and the only thing that fixed it was installing Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (Offline Installer)
    https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642

I also installed SQL Server 2014 Client tools earlier, and this may also have had a positive impact by installing a newer msxml 6.0 version.

My error messsage was:

[A]xx.xxxx.ClassUserDS cannot be cast to [B]xx.xxxx.ClassUserDS. Type A originates from 'yyyyyy, Version=3.0.5617.31787, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=657d68e01eb7c911' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Users\xxxxx\Appdata\Local\assembly\dl3\QQ3VBMNC.EO1\VYVECOB7.H5J\2b6c89d2\51158eea_9892d001\yyyyyy.DLL'. Type B orginates from 'yyyyyy, Version=3.0.5617.31787' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Users\xxxxx\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\InfoPath\FormCache4\30083E69.D18\cd264661b1055c58$b04f2786908cb791\yyyyyy.dll

I tried looking in regedit HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\  all I could see there was the path that is mentioned in the error message, interesting nonetheless.